# Python Gtk 3.0: How to grab focus inside Notebook

Tags: python, gtk, gtk3

I'm trying to set the focus to an `Entry` input field. If I put it inside a `Box`, I can set the focus via the `grab_focus` method. But if the `Entry` is inside a `Notebook`, it is not focused.

Example code:

```py
import gi

gi.require_version("Gtk", "3.0")
from gi.repository import Gtk


class MyWindow(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="Simple Notebook Example")
        self.set_border_width(3)

        self.notebook = Gtk.Notebook()
        self.add(self.notebook)

        self.page1 = Gtk.Box()
        self.page1.set_border_width(10)
        self.page1.add(Gtk.Label(label="Default Page!"))
        self.notebook.append_page(self.page1, Gtk.Label(label="Plain Title"))

        self.note = Gtk.Entry()
        self.note.set_activates_default(True)
        self.note.set_text("")
        self.page1.add(self.note)

        self.page2 = Gtk.Box()
        self.page2.set_border_width(10)
        self.page2.add(Gtk.Label(label="A page with an image for a Title."))
        self.notebook.append_page(
            self.page2, Gtk.Image.new_from_icon_name("help-about", Gtk.IconSize.MENU)
        )

        self.note.grab_focus()  # does not work


win = MyWindow()
win.connect("destroy", Gtk.main_quit)
win.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

How can I focus `self.note` inside the notebook?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it [turns out](https://discourse.gnome.org/t/python-gtk-3-0-how-to-grab-focus-inside-notebook/6626), you can only grab focus to visible widgets.

Calling `grab_focus` after `show_all` makes the example work:

```
win = MyWindow()
win.connect("destroy", Gtk.main_quit)
win.show_all()
win.note.grab_focus()
Gtk.main()
```